# Redux обновляется с задержкой

Tags: redux, reactjs

Когда я обновляю Redux через компонент, само хранилище не обновляется мгновенно, а с задержкой. Почему так происходит? Использую [react-starter-kit/redux](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/tree/feature/redux)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам компонент:

```
class ArticleList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.props = props;    
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let { reduxKey, articles, actions } = this.props; // key in redux storage
    this.props.actions.initAll(reduxKey); // init key in redux; to prevent errors
    let store = this.props.store[reduxKey]; // current storage in redux

    // pass mainkey in context also
    this.store = store;

    console.log("inComponent: ", store, this.props.store);
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("setTimeout: ", this.props.store, store)
    }.bind(this), 0)
  }

  async load() {
    return await this.props.actions.fetchArticles(this.props.query, this.props.key, this.store.latest + 10);
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
    store: state.article
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(articleActions, dispatch)
  })
)(ArticleList);
```

Его вызов:

```
<div>
                <ArticleList reduxKey="home" query="filter[tag__not_in]=44" articles={this.props.articles}/>
              </div>
              <div>
                <ArticleList reduxKey="recent" query="" articles={[]}/>
              </div>
              <div>
                <ArticleList reduxKey="life" query="filter[cat]=6" articles={[]}/>
              </div>
```

Reducer:

```
import { UPDATE_ARTICLE } from '../actions/article';

export default function runtime(state = {}, action) {
  const { type, tag, articles = [], latest = 1, loading = false, max = 999 } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_ARTICLE:
      console.log("State before: ", state);
      let arts = state[tag] ? state[tag] : { articles: [] };

      arts = {
        articles: [
          ...arts.articles,
          ...articles,
        ],
        latest,
        loading,
        max
      };

      console.log("State after: ", state);
      return {
        ...state,
        [tag]: arts
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Action:

```
import fetch from '../core/fetch';

export const UPDATE_ARTICLE = "article.update";

export function setArticles(tag, articles, latest, loading, max) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ARTICLE,
    tag,
    articles,
    latest,
    loading,
    max
  }
}

export function initAll (tag) {
  return (dispatch) => (dispatch(setArticles(tag, [], 1, false, null)))
}

export function fetchArticles (filter, tag, latest) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    let page = latest / 10;

    dispatch(setArticles(tag, [], latest, true, null)); // set loading indicator
    const resp = await fetch("http://local.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?fields=categories,date,short,title,id&per_page=10&"+filter + "&page=" + (latest / 10), {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    })

    const data = await resp.json();

    dispatch(setArticles(tag, data, latest, false, resp.headers.get("X-WP-Total"))); // dispatch action
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Еще не прочитал вопрос до конца, но пожалуйста используйте Redux DevTools :)

Comment: это было 4 года назад... @FrogFrogov

Comment: Поставил фильтрацию по вопросам без ответа не посмотрел на дату ))